# Only call in function is pass, but function still does something?

Tags: python

Hi!

I'm currently looking through the python code for the album art finder located here: 
 
https://github.com/skyostil/albumart
and as I look through the code, I'm stumped by how a set of methods function.

The file I'm looking at is /lib/albumart/albumart.py

The Module, Source, Target, and Recognizer class are the parts where I am stuck. For each of these classes, their methods all take parameters, but all that is done inside the class is pass. However, according to the comments, the methods do something? Can someone explain exactly how there is something done?

Here is an excerpt of the code.

```
class Target(Module):
  #A virtual base class that defines an album cover target
  def gPassetCover(self, path):
    #Returns a cover image for the given path or None if one isn't found
    pass
  def setCover(self, path, cover):
    #Assigns a cover image to the given path. Note that the path may also point to a file
    pass
  def removeCover(path):
    #Removes the album image for the given path. Note that the path may also point to a file
    pass
  def hasCover(self, path):
    #Returns 1 if the given path has an associated cover image and 0 otherwise.
    return 0
```

Comment: That is a base class, they're just placeholders - the methods will be implemented in subclasses. The usual convention is to `raise NotImplementedError`.

Comment: so basically like an interface?

Comment: Yes, pretty much, but without the enforcement. This defines the methods that subclasses should have; and that don't implement will fall back to the base class implementation (which does nothing, in this case), rather than fail on `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that class is meant to be extended so as to provide concrete functionality (i.e. it's a sort of [abstract type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_type)), judging from *"a virtual base class"*.

The methods of `Target` themselves do nothing (`pass` is a [NOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP)).

Comment: How can you tell it was extended? I've been looking for where it may have been extended, but ahve been unsuccessful

Comment: @AsAFink Search for `(albumart.Target):` to find subclasses, e.g. https://github.com/skyostil/albumart/blob/master/lib/albumart/albumart_target_generic.py

Answer (score 1):

Nope, from the official python docs:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements

> The pass statement does nothing. It can be used when a statement is
>   required syntactically but the program requires no action.